# Creating a listbox using SQL in the row source

Tags: sql, database, forms, ms-access, listbox

In my textbook I'm at this step.

[Step in textbook and error message in red border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UgO4.png)

I use this code to populate the listbox:

SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE [Type]=5 And Left([Name],1)<>“~” ORDER BY [Name];

[Picture of listbox property sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDI6r.png)

I've tried copying it twice to account for any misspellings and I keep getting syntax errors?

Comment: What error is it showing, exactly?

Comment: In the first picture the dialog box with the red border is the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy-paste query text, it copied wrong type of quotes (`“”`). Replace them manually to normal ones (`""`):

```
SELECT MSysObjects.[Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=5) And ((Left([Name],1))<>"~")) ORDER BY MSysObjects.[Name];
```

Text editors very often convert strait quotes to open and closing quotes, which are letters, not special charactes